# admin menu missing when upgrading from drupal 6 to drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I just upgraded my website from Drupal 6 to drupal 7. For some reason the new administration menu that is suppose to go across the top of the page is not showing up at all. I have followed the upgrade path directions without success.

I have also tried re uploading the sites / all and themes directories but that did not change anything. I have ran update.php as well.

Thanks..

Comment: admin menu from the admin_menu module? If this is it, just delete the module you have there, and upload the new version of the module and enable it.

Comment: The admin_menu module seems to work perfectly. It is the drupal menu I am missing.

Comment: how about you just re-create a menu and add it to the top of the page? Saying this, upgrading from D6 to 7 is not something i would advise, due to the major changes made from 6 to 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the core module, Toolbar, enabled?  If not, go to *your site*/?q=admin/modules and enable it.  Also, if you're not using Garland or some other generic theme, enable one for administrative use.  It's possible your theme is overwriting the region where the toolbar is supposed to dispaly

Comment: That was it! I did not know it had to be enabled. So obvious.. thannks!

Comment: It is interesting to notice that this module is enabled when installing Drupal 7 from scratch, So the problem is only for upgraders since the upgrade process does not enable this new module by default. It should do that IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and it was not just the top menu not showing up, the appearance and module link were not accessible at all.

turns out it was because the user account I used to login was not the FIRST user aka the SUPER user. Since I don't have the password of the "first" admin user, I had to change the UID of my user account to 1.
You can create a new user with UID = 1

INSERT INTO users (uid, name, pass) VALUES ('1', 'yourname', md5('yourpassword'));